# Complex Number from datatable

Tags: c#, complex-numbers

I added the complex number (real, Imaginary) into the data-table then need to do some mathematical calculation.

Let's say:

```
DataTable dtB_01 = new DataTable();
dtB_01.Columns.Add("d1");
dtB_01.Columns.Add("d2");
dtB_01.Columns.Add("d3");
dtB_01.Columns.Add("d4");

DataRow bRow;
bRow = dtB_01.NewRow();
dtB_01.Rows.Add(bRow);
bRow["d1"] = new Complex(double.Parse("6"), double.Parse("2"));
bRow["d2"] = new Complex(double.Parse("8"), double.Parse("3")); 
bRow["d3"] = Complex.Subtract((Complex)bRow["d1"], (Complex)bRow["d2"]);
bRow["d4"] = Complex.Add((Complex)bRow["d1"], (Complex)bRow["d2"]);
```

But it doesn't work, any advice? The below 2 lines doesn't work

```
bRow["d3"] = Complex.Subtract((Complex)bRow["d1"], (Complex)bRow["d2"]);
bRow["d4"] = Complex.Add((Complex)bRow["d1"], (Complex)bRow["d2"]);
```

And my data is more than a thousand rows, that bRow["d3"] actually is using data from different rows.

Comment: Can we see the rest of the relevant code?

Comment: What error or exception message is occurring?

Answer (score 2):

A DataTable is not a general-purpose collection in .Net.  It’s specifically for storing database data in memory.

So it only supports types that are commonly used in database systems, and Complex isn’t one of them. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_DataColumn_DataType

You can simply use a List of tuples, like this:

```
var tdB_01 = new List<(Complex d1, Complex d2, Complex d3, Complex d4)>();
var d1 = new Complex(6, 2);
var d2 = new Complex(8, 3);
var d3 = d2 - d1;
var d4 = d1 + d2;
tdB_01.Add((d1, d2, d3, d4));
```

Comment: I consist a lot of data and need to do some complex number calculation. So I will read all data into the data table then do the math for the next step.

Comment: @Kenneth David is saying that you cannot use `DataTable` for that.